# Is there a better way to detect if nextUntil stopped regularly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, nextuntil

I wonder if there is a well performing way to find out if `.nextUntil()` stopped without matching the specified selector.

`.nextUntil()` returns the same result as `.nextAll()` if the selector didn't match any element.

So it is possible to find out using:

```
if ($("#id").nextUntil(".someclass").length === $("#id").nextAll().length) {
  //do some stuff if there was no match
}
```

But is there a better solution?

Comment: You already have a typo `nextUnil`... so it's probably not gonna match anything :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it stops without a match, it means that you have a last child inside your object. You can use the following:

```
if (!$("#id").nextUntil(".someclass").is(':last-child'))
```

[Test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qkn7e/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this is certainly better than using `nextAll`